# How to display date data according to the amount of information contained in the database?

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I display the number of descriptions by date, I encounter a problem. That is, the number of descriptions does not match what is in my database.

This is the table from My database

[image]

This is result :

```
----------------------------------------------------
|      Tanggal      |   A  |   I   |   S   |   H   |
----------------------------------------------------
|     2018-01-01    |   1  |   1   |   3   |   1   |  
|     2018-01-02    |   1  |   1   |   3   |   1   |
----------------------------------------------------
```

It should be like this :

```
----------------------------------------------------
|      Tanggal      |   A  |   I   |   S   |   H   |
----------------------------------------------------
|     2018-01-01    |   1  |   1   |   0   |   1   |  
|     2018-01-02    |   0  |   0   |   3   |   0   |
----------------------------------------------------
```

This is My Controllers :

```
public function absen()
{
    $data['getall'] = $this->m_absen->getall();

    $data['alpa']   = $this->m_absen->alpa();

    $data['izin']   = $this->m_absen->izin();

    $data['sakit']  = $this->m_absen->sakit();

    $data['hadir']  = $this->m_absen->hadir();

    $this->load->view('admin/absen/v_absen', $data);
}
```

This is My Models :

```
public function getall()
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_absen_siswa group by tanggal");
    return $query->result();
}

public function alpa()
{
    $query = $this->db->query("select count(*) as total_alpa from tbl_absen_siswa where keterangan='A'");
    return $query->row();
}

public function izin()
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_izin FROM tbl_absen_siswa WHERE keterangan='I'");
    return $query->row();
}

public function sakit()
{
    $query = $this->db->query("select count(*) as total_sakit, nama_siswa from tbl_absen_siswa where keterangan='S'");
    return $query->row();       
}

public function hadir()
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_hadir FROM tbl_absen_siswa  WHERE keterangan='H'");
    return $query->row();
}
```

This is My Views :

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dt-responsive" width="100%" id="sample_1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="5%">Tanggal</th>
            <th width="3%">A</th>
            <th width="3%">I</th>
            <th width="3%">S</th>
            <th width="3%">H</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($getall as $g){ ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $g->tanggal; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $alpa->total_alpa; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $izin->total_izin; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $sakit->total_sakit; ?>
            <td><?php echo $hadir->total_hadir; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need one query for that kind of task

your model

```
public function getall()
{
    $query = $this->db
        ->select('tanggal, count(keterangan) AS count, keterangan')
        ->from('tbl_absen_siswa')
        ->group_by('tanggal, keterangan')
        ->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

your controller

```
public function absen()
{
    $arrResult = $this->m_absen->getall();
    $arrData = [];

    foreach($arrResult AS $objItem)
    {
        $arrData[$objItem->tanggal][$objItem->keterangan] = $objItem->count;
    }
    $this->load->view('so/so50683515', array('arrData' => $arrData));
}
```

and your view

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dt-responsive" width="100%" id="sample_1">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="5%">Tanggal</th>
        <th width="3%">A</th>
        <th width="3%">I</th>
        <th width="3%">S</th>
        <th width="3%">H</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach($arrData as $date => $arrItem)
    {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $date; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo (isset($arrItem['A']))   ?   $arrItem['A']   :   0; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo (isset($arrItem['I']))   ?   $arrItem['I']   :   0; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo (isset($arrItem['S']))   ?   $arrItem['S']   :   0; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo (isset($arrItem['H']))   ?   $arrItem['H']   :   0; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Forgive me. I'm new on stackoverflow, so I do not know the feature to receive your question yet

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa